# Go to override method definition in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions

I guess there's no built-in funcionality in Visual Studio for this purpose, but I would be happy if someone could direct me to (free one, if possible) extension that can do this.

```
    public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Annoy annoy = new Tubo();
        annoy.DoTubo();
    }
}

public class Annoy
{
    public virtual void DoTubo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Annoy.DoTubo()");
    }
}

public class Tubo : Annoy
{
    public override void DoTubo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tubo.DoTubo()");
    }
}
```

When I go with `F12` (Go to definition), the carret navigates to `Annoy.DoTubo()` and not to `Tubo.DoTubo()`.
I've found a plugin for the similar purpose (only for classes impelementing interface and not classes inheriting other classes) [here](http://blog.rthand.com/page/Go-To-Implementator.aspx).
I guess ReSharper and VisualAssist has this functionlaity, but I'm looking for a free one if there's any.

Comment: `annoy` is declared as an `Annoy` object; the `DoTubbo` method is being called from the `Annoy` class due to the variable declaration. How would VS know to go to the base class?

Comment: @MetroSmurf moreover what if it's `Annoy annoy = AnnoyFactory("Tubo");`

Comment: @ConradFrix - that would just be annoying...

Comment: what if his object was actually declared as an Tubo? the "go to definition" would still jump to the base class definition. Is there an actual way to navigate to the actual doTubo function that is attached to the object?

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2015, you can use the right-click Context menu on the base method to call "Go to Implementation" which will list out the methods overriding the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find it without any tool is to look for all references, that'll find the usages of the method.

A free one is the CodeRush by DevExpress

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember there is build in "Find all references" in Visual Studio's context menu, so there is no need in third party tools

Answer (score 0):

In Mac:
From Definition to Implementation: Cmd+ F12

Hover to read the Definition of Method Implementation.